# Best way to loop waiting for a small background task?

Tags: android

I have an app that streams audio. In a separate thread I call my service to start while displaying a progress dialog to the user. The `Service` will either start the audio or have an error within 10 or so seconds. The hacky way I have it now is that when the `Service` has determined that the audio is either prepped and ready or an error, it sends a local broadcast message back to my `Activity` with that info. This signals my main activity that the service is done loading and prepping the media and I can dismiss the progress dialog, etc.

Right now I have the `MainActivity` just waiting in a `do while` loop, displaying a progress dialog, checking a variable until it receives the broadcast from the service which changes said variable

I know that this is *probably* not the right way to do this so my question is, what is the proper way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of the loop. The `ProgressDialog` should be sufficient. Just dismiss it when the broadcast is received.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of busy waiting is definitely not a good idea for handling this kind of situation. You might consider having an interface declared like this.

```
public interface MediaResponseListener {
    void mediaResponseReceiver(String result);
}
```

Then you need to implement the `interface` in your `MainActivity` like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MediaResponseListener {
    // Your onCreate and other function goes here 

    // Then you need to implement the function of your interface 
    @Override
    public void mediaResponseReceiver(String result) {
        // Do something with the result 
    }
}
```

Now you declare an `interface` in your `Service` class too and when you're starting the `Service` from your `MainActivity` pass the reference of the `interface`. So your `Service` may look like this.

```
public AudioService extends Service {

    // Declare an interface 
    public MediaResponseListener mMediaResponseListener; 

    // ... Your code 

    // When some error occurs or you want to send some information to the launching Activity 

    mMediaResponseListener.mediaResponseReceiver(result);
}
```

And while starting the `Service` from your `Activity` you need to pass the reference of the `interface` to the `Service`. So in your `MainActivity` you need to do something like this.

```
private AudioService mAudioService; 
mAudioService. mMediaResponseListener = this;
startService();
```

Here's how you can avoid the busy waiting and can receive the response from the `Service` time to time.

Now the behaviour can be achieved in many other ways, like you've already tried with local broadcast.

So why don't you just declare a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity` which will be invoked when any `Broadcast` is received from the `Service`.

[Here's a nice implementation of how you can send and receive broadcast.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/3145960)